# Centre align inside THEAD, TR or TFOOT

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I'm using a grid - here's the code:

```
.grid-container
{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:96rem;
}

<div class="table-middle">
    <div class="grid-container">
        <p>This is some kind of widget with no SEO value</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The outer div allows me to paint the background to the edges of the page whilst the grid container is aligned centrally with a max width of 96rem.

But I also need to alter the order of 3 divs. The trick I learned is to use table displays like this:

```
.table-top
{
    display:table-header-group;
}

.table-middle
{
    display:table-row-group;
}

.table-bottom
{
    display:table-footer-group;
}
```

This allows me to put my html in any order inside the parent and reorder it using these styles.

However, I now need to combine the 2 - so centre the inner div inside the table row group insead of a div.

The current classes don't work together, but I know nothing about tables.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: don't use tables for stuff like that imo

Comment: But I don't there is another way to reorder my divs using html/css alone

Comment: If you want to play with div order within css - have you tried flexbox? [https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) It has good resources for manipulating divs with CSS.

Comment: Good answer and great resource for flexbox virgins like myself - shame there is no support for IE9 - difficult to find a fallback for what I'm trying to do. But hey, I've already dropped the XP brigade entirely, so the Vista boys are just gonna have to deal with this minor inconvenience..

Comment: @John Ohara. From there, the fallback for IE with flexbox is mainly about specifying the rows as inline-block - although this then doesn't solve your issue with ordering the columns. It's a good one to get on with as it does solve a lot of common issues. Best of luck with experimenting.